# Is it possible to specify different ACLs for different folders in the same storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, acl, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, gsutil

I would like to specify different default ACL levels for two different folders in the same Google Cloud storage bucket. Is this even possible, or is there perhaps some workaround available?

It seems to be possible retroactively specify different ACL levels for different folders using the [`gsutil acl`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) command, whereas it is only possible to use the [`gsutil defacl`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/defacl) command on the entire bucket. Correct?

Some potential workarounds I've been brainstorming, but not found any support for yet:

1. Set each files specific ACL from the client-side (iOS/Android) when it is first uploaded.
2. Have a Cloud Function listen for new file uploads and then modify it's ACL accordingly.

Again, I have not found any clues in the official documentation towards implementing any of the above solutions, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, ACLs can only be applied to individual objects, and IAM policies can only be applied to entire buckets or individual objects.

Your two proposed solutions are both reasonable but both have drawbacks. The first solution would be best, but only if you trust the iOS user to set good permissions. The client could potentially set different permissions. That's not necessarily a problem, since presumably the client already has the data and, if they were malicious, could already share it anywhere it wanted to, but it's something to be aware of.

The second solution is also fine, but there's a very small window of time wherein the object's ACLs would be incorrect. That may also not be a problem for you.

One nice variation might be to have users upload the objects to a "staging" bucket, and then have a Cloud Function respond to that upload by moving the object to its production location with the correct ACL, then delete the staged version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Do you by any chance have any sample code or can point me to the right documentation for how to set ACL from either a client or from a Cloud Function? Is it possible to use gsutil directly from a Cloud Function perhaps?